# Fatal Error while trying to export a result of a query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I execute this query :

```
SELECT 
   `COD_AG`,
   `NUM_CONJ`,
   `SIT_CONJ`,
   `PRF_CONJ`,
   `NAT_CONJ`,
   `NOM_PR_CONJ`,
   `DOTI_CONJ`,
   `CIN_A_CONJ`,
   `CIN_N_CONJ`,
   `DAT_SIT_CONJ`
FROM
   `gipeord_conjoint`,
   `gestion_delegation`.`dataidentifpersonnel`
WHERE
   `gipeord_conjoint`.`COD_AG`=`gestion_delegation`.`dataidentifpersonnel`.`PPR`
```

and then I have 2363 results and i select all records then click on export button to get the results in a sql file but i get this error :

> **Fatal error**:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in
>   **C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\libraries\sqlparser.lib.php** on
>   line **271**

I changed parameters in the file php.ini but no change. What's the wrong here?

I applied that in phpmyadmin. (mysql)

Comment: Did you restart your web server after you made the change to the php.ini file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from changing the max_execution time in php.ini, you also need to change it in PHPMyAdmin's configs.

Locate `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\libraries\config.default.php`and change `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']` as needed.

Make sure you restart Apache.

Comment: Oh My god I get it ! Yes it was the file config.default.php which must be changed. Thank You ! [RESOLVED]

Comment: Glad to have helped. Please accept the answer (by clicking the check mark on the left) so it can be marked as such.