# Attempted SQL import exceeds execution time limit

Tags: mysql, sql, import, phpmyadmin

When I am trying to load an SQL file into wamp using phpmyadmin I am getting the fatal error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.5.1\libraries\plugins\import\ImportSql.class.php on line 220

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Location: C:\xampp\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;
```

In C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Look for and Change `max_execution_time`

you already have execution 300 seconds, so go to that file and increase `max_execution_time` to to what ever you want of seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line

**$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;**

to  **phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**

And Change **php.ini** and **my.ini**

- post_max_size = 750M
- upload_max_filesize = 750M
- max_execution_time = 5000
- max_input_time = 5000
- memory_limit = 1000M
- max_allowed_packet = 200M (in my.ini)

**OR**

You may also go to **xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php**,

and change this line to fix that error.

**$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;**

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading huge sql file. So php cannot executed all queries within a default time limit. You need to change the php execution time limit.

Your Answer is solved in [Fatal Error while trying to export a result of a query in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489951/fatal-error-while-trying-to-export-a-result-of-a-query-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help you please refer: http://www.nginxtips.com/configure-max_execution_time-in-php-fpm-using-nginx/